# Стартуют не все потоки из списка.

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть простой код:

```
List<Thread> treads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final MyClass obj : objList) {
            treads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    obj.work();
                }
            }));
        }

        for (Thread th : treads) {
            th.start();
        }

        for (Thread th : treads) {
            try {
                th.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Объектов в списке objList немного. Штук 10. Но стартуют и начинают работать только некоторые порождённые потоки. По разному. Бывает 3, 4 или 5.

Как быть?

Comment: Не хотите попробовать ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: А как вы определяете, что они не стартуют? Может, они стартуют, но вылетают с Exeption'ом до того как вы приджоиниваете их к основному потоку? Попробуйте обернуть код `MyClass.work()` в try-catch и писать в лог, если там выбрасывается Exception.

Comment: @Виталий Кустов Откуда уверенность, что стартуют не все потоки? Не выбрасывает ли метод obj.work() исключения? Думаю логирование в коде исполняемого внутри потока вам поможет.

Comment: Я 100% уверен что они не стартуют. Там и логирование и качественная обработка и исключений и всё на свете. НЕ могу понять почему не стартуют. Кто-нибудь может пояснить 1й коммент? Что за ThreadPoolExecutor? и с чем его едят?

Comment: @Виталий Кустов Хотя бы до цикла с th.join ваш код добирается? Касаемо ThreadPoolExecutor (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html ) вам намекают, что вместо идиомы start/join, можно использовать Executor.invokeAll()

Comment: Да. Добирается. Проблема глубже сидела. Пофиксил. Спасибо за ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @Виталий Кустов И в чем же состояла проблема, позвольте полюбопытствовать?

Comment: Рассказывать долго, потому как блаблабла... Короче в методе work() проблема.

Answer (score 1):

В твоем коде, который я запустил, все верно, так что проблема в методе work или вообще твоем объекте.

```
public class StartClass {
    private static Logger logger;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> objList = new ArrayList<MyClass>(10);
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            objList.add(new MyClass());
        }
        List<Thread> treads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (final MyClass obj : objList) {
            treads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    obj.work();
                }
            }));
        }

        for (Thread th : treads) {
            th.start();
        }

        for (Thread th : treads) {
            try {
                th.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
class MyClass {
    private static int i;
    public void work() {
        System.out.println(i++);
    }
}
```

Выводит:

> 0 
> 2 
> 1 
> 3 
> 5 
> 4 
> 6 
> 7 
> 8 
> 9 
> Process finished with exit code 0